# Rest Api to get the token from vault using aws auth

Tags: hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to build the rest API for the below command where I can get the vault token

CMD:
**vault login -token-only -no-store -method=aws -path=path-value role=role-value**

the above command returns the token for the vault and I need to convert this command to an API request
I am going through the docs And I don't find anything similar to my requirement Also I am new to Hashicorp Vault.

docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/aws#aws-auth-method-api

Can someone help me get a Rest call for the above command?

Comment: What language are you using to authenticate with the AWS auth engine via the REST API?

Comment: I am using Java. I am trying to Convert the command into a curl request to verify and then I can convert it into a Java Rest call.

Comment: Using Spring along with Java.

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/aws#login Isn't this the API you're looking to call?

Answer (score 0):

It is documented under the Login operation.

The `token-only` and `no-store` are flags for the [built-in token helper](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/token-helper) in Vault cli. You can ignore them as curl doesn't do any of that anyway.

Assuming your command line works, here is how you would the equivalent with `curl/bash`.

So with the following variables defined in your shell:

```
VAULT_ADDR=https://myvaulthost.example.com
PATH_VALUE=path-value
ROLE_VALUE=role-value
```

Beware of the trailing slash at the end of `VAULT_ADDR`. You can then login with this command:

```
curl ${VAULT_ADDR}/auth/$PATH_VALUE/login \
   --header "Expect:" \
   --header 'Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8' \
   --data @- <<EOF
{ "role"="${ROLE_VALUE}" }
EOF
```

Comment: But how can I tell that Iam using the AWS auth for authentication in curl request?

Comment: It is an authentication method. You indicate that with the `/auth` prefix. Then you specify the name of the AWS authentication mount, which in your question looks like it is `path-value`. Probably you used `aws` when you [enabled it](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/auth/aws#enable-aws-ec2-authentication-in-vault). Vault will route the request to that auth module, without really knowing what it will do with it. Every Vault authentication module implements the same interface. You select the one you want by specifying its path (and the `auth` prefix).